# When and why did the shape of Captain America's shield change?

Tags: marvel, comics, weapon, captain-america

In his first appearances, Captain America's shield is an elongated triangle with three peaks at the top:

[image: Original sketch of Captain America]

<sub>Joe Simon's first sketch of Captain America</sub>

[image: Kite-shaped shield]

<sub>Cover of Captain America issue #1, 1941</sub>

Now, of course, his shield is round.

[image: Captain America with rounded shield]

<sub>Late 60's issue of Captain America</sub>

When did this change occur, and why?

Comment: When? No idea. Why? Also no idea, though I'd speculate that it was accompanied by a shift in his fighting style; the round shield would allow it to be thrown, just like it is in the MCU, whereas the kite shield would be at best a purely melee weapon, if not entirely for defensive purposes.

Comment: I know Stan Lee created the round shield.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## From Elongated Triangle to Kite-shape shield

I cannot find any in-universe reason as to why this occurred, but **out-of-universe** I can.

Apparently the original sketch of Captain America came  to the attention of Archie Comics (then MLJ Magazines) - they noticed there was a similarity between Captain America's shield and the chest detail of their own character [The Shield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shield_%28Archie_Comics%29) (below).

[image: The Shield]

Consequently, Captain America's shield was changed to the Kite design.

(Source: Cronin, Brian (2009). Was Superman a Spy?: And Other Comic Book Legends Revealed. Plume. pp. 135–136. ISBN 978-0-452-29532-2.)

## From Kite shape shield to Round shield

### When

The Marvel Wikia site refers to President F D Roosevelt presenting Captain America with this.  This puts it **between 1933 and 1945**

[image: Franklin D Roosevelt presenting Captain America with his new shield]

From *Captain America Vol 1 255: 'The Living Legend'* in which

> It details the origin of Captain America and focuses on his early
>   adventures in **1941-42**.

### Why

As correctly pointed out in the question:

> Rogers was originally issued a traditionally "kite" shaped shield made
>   of *mundane steel*, as well as a sidearm.

([Source](http://marvel.wikia.com/Captain_America_%28Steven_Rogers%29))

This new disc-shaped shield, however, had two main advantages:

**1: It was better as an offensive weapon**

He discovered:

> that its excellent aerodynamic properties made it an
>   effective offensive weapon

([Source](http://marvel.wikia.com/Captain_America_%28Steven_Rogers%29))

**2: It was made of a nearly indestructible alloy**

> Originally, Dr. Myron MacLain was attempting to perfect an
>   indestructible alloy as strong as the legendary 'Adamantine', which
>   Hercules' Golden Mace was made from. Dr. MacLain was hoping the alloy
>   would provide a distinct advantage in the armor of American war
>   machines, during World War II. The Doctor worked tirelessly, **using the
>   exotic Vibranium metal and an unknown substance**. While the Doctor was
>   asleep, as a result of his exhaustion, an unknown factor caused the
>   metals he was working with to bond.

([Source](http://marvel.wikia.com/Captain_America%27s_Shield))

An almost indestructible shield has obvious advantages over one made from 'mundane steel'!

Not only is the shield nearly indestructible though, it also has other useful properties which are inherent to [Wakandan Vibranium](http://marvel.wikia.com/Vibranium), namely the ability to absorb vibratory energies in the vicinity.

The [Wiki page on his shield](http://marvel.wikia.com/Captain_America%27s_Shield) explains the following (however bear in mind that it does not *reference* the said sources):

> Some sources say that Dr. MacLain chose the discus shape **because of
>   its versatility**, while other say that he **used an existing cast
>   designed for tank hatches.**

Comment: went out for lunch, so got late to post, great answer +1

Comment: Re: "Some sources say that Dr. MacLain chose the discus shape because of its versatility, while other say that he used an existing cast designed for tank hatches": Conveniently, these claims are compatible: perhaps he selected the discus shape for versatility, and used the existing cast because it happened to provide the selected shape.

Comment: "able to throw it twice as far" - he was throwing the kite shield around already?

Comment: Great answer, +1 and many thanks.

Comment: @user2813274 yes, he threw the kite shield as well.

Comment: @DCShannon Originally it wasn't a kite design, it was more of the elongated triangle.  It was *then* changed to the kite design

Comment: @DCShannon Yes, the first picture in the question is of the original Captain America.  The problem was that the original shield of Captain America was too similar to the design on the chest of The Shield, so they changed the design of Captain America's shield.

Comment: @DCShannon There were three shields.  I'm sorry if I didn't make that clear.  Basically there was the shield which is like an elongated triangle from the first comic.  The second is the kite-shaped shield in the second comic onwards (note the slightly different shaped shield in the second picture in the question).  Then there was the third shield which was disc-shaped.  I address the matters of the first elongated triangle shield in the first section of my answer

Comment: @DCShannon ah an oversight on my part; the first image is the original sketch, the second from the first comic. I'll amend it momentarily

Comment: Okay, there we go, thanks. So you're saying the design changed from that sketch to the first comic. The only difference I see is that the top becomes more rounded. Is that it?

Comment: @DCShannon Yep - the only real difference was the top becoming more rounded.  It seems to have satisfied MLJ!

Comment: That's interesting, and I'm glad to have heard about it. However, this means MLJ doesn't actually have anything to do with the switch to a disc-shaped shield, which is what the question was asking about, right?

Comment: @DCShannon the question asks when and why the shield changed and, as the shield changed twice it does apply to the question.  The question doesn't specifically ask why there was a switch to a disc-shaped shield

Answer (score 9):

In-universe, Captain America got round shield in 1941. See the middle-right panel of this page from *Avengers (1963) #71*:

[image]

The same panel also shows why Cap wanted to get a round shield.

**Note:** This comics doesn't give any out-of-universe cue. When the comics came out, Cap already had round shield. In this scene, three Avengers (Black Panther, Yellow jacket and Vision) are in past when Cap didn't know anything about the Avengers.

**Update:**
Out-of-universe, Captain America first appeared with round shield in [Captain America comics #2](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/7860/captain_america_comics_1941_2) (Published: April 01, 1941). You can see it on the cover:

[image]

The first page:

[image]

In the [previous issue](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/7849/captain_america_comics_1941_1) which was published on March 01, 1941 (whose cover you've included in the question), Captain America kept using that kite/badge shaped shield until the end.

They suddenly changed the design of the shield without giving any in-universe explanation at the time.

Comment: A side note on the story from *Avengers* 71; almost ten years later, when Roy Thomas was writing the adventures of Cap, the Human Torch, Namor, et al. during World War II as the super-hero team the *Invaders*, he retold this story from the viewpoint of the WWII heroes. However, Cap and Namor both resembled their present day selves (round shield, and green scale trunks, respectively). So, the story had to cover why they looked like they did in the Avengers story. Presumably, the shield switch was made in *Avengers* 71 to make it clear that this was Cap from the past.

Comment: Did the Submariner swim in the Seine, and survive? That guy *really* has strong superpowers!

Answer (score 0):

Captain America's first shield was badge-shaped. After complaints by a rival comic company that it too closely resembled their hero's symbol, Captain's shield was replaced in Captain America #2 with a disc shaped version.

Comment: This seems to only be a *vague* reiteration of one point from the accepted answer.